# Flask admin s3 SSL error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, flask, boto3

I'm trying to use a couple different implementations of uploading files to S3 from Flask Admin. In both situations I'm getting an SSL error. I've tried a few things that I've found such as adding this to config:

```
    S3_USE_HTTPS = False
```

I also updated the certifi package which I saw recommended on another thread. I can't solve this error. Any idea why I'm getting this?

Error msg below:

```
> File
> "/Users/kevin/dev/allstarrma/flask-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/connection.py",
> line 1071, in make_request
>     retry_handler=retry_handler)   File "/Users/kevin/dev/allstarrma/flask-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/connection.py",
> line 1030, in _mexe
>     raise ex   File "/Users/kevin/dev/allstarrma/flask-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto/connection.py",
> line 943, in _mexe
>     request.body, request.headers)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py",
> line 1239, in request
>     self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py",
> line 1285, in _send_request
>     self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py",
> line 1234, in endheaders
>     self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py",
> line 1026, in _send_output
>     self.send(msg)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py",
> line 964, in send
>     self.connect()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py",
> line 1400, in connect
>     server_hostname=server_hostname)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py",
> line 407, in wrap_socket
>     _context=self, _session=session)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py",
> line 814, in __init__
>     self.do_handshake()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py",
> line 1068, in do_handshake
>     self._sslobj.do_handshake()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py",
> line 689, in do_handshake
>     self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)
```

Comment: Note **this won't solve root cause**, but you can invoke python script with PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0, so from command line it would look like `PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0 /path/to/script.py`. Python ssl shouldn't complain about certification anymore.

Comment: What about when i deploy to heroku?

Answer (score 0):

information about default https verification can be found:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0476/

There is also great article from Red Hat.
https://access.redhat.com/articles/2039753 Right now it's open, but in case of being behind pay-wall I decided to write key points.

As said in comment you can invoke your python scripts with `PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0 /path/to/script.py`

You can also configure - default behaviour in file `/etc/python/cert-verification.cfg` and change

```
[https]
verify=platform_default
```

to

```
[https]
verify=disable
```

If you are using up to date python 2.7 you can also use in order to dynamically disable cert verification.

```
import ssl
ssl._https_verify_certificates(0)
```

Unfortunately for Python > 3.4 (I tried 3.4.5 and 3.6.3) I wasn't able to find similar function. Same result in documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html.